# Sampling realizations in multidimensional array in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multidimensional-array, sample

Basically, I want to sample 9 independent realizations for the uniform distribution U(0,1) 2578 times, and this works fine, using either

```
replicate(2578,{runif(9,0,1)})
```

or

```
F=c()
for (i in 1:2578){
 F[i,]=runif(9,0,1)
}
```

Now I want this to be repeated let's say 10 times, i.e. creating 10 new 2578x9 samples. I want to create a multidimensional array, or to visualize it better a rectangular parallelepiped with length 9, height 2578, and width whatever (10, 1000, 100000, ...). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your simulated data could benefit from being structured directly into an array: that would make them much easier to handle:

```
dims <- c(2578, 9, 100)
tmp <- runif(prod(dims))
A <- array(tmp, dims)
```